# Convert Utc to custom timezone using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wrote the the below function to convert a UTC time into custom timezone using momentjs

```js
function convert(time, timezone) {

  time = moment.utc(time, 'h:mm a').tz(timezone);
  return time

}

console.log(convert('06:21pm', 'America/New_York'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone.min.js" integrity="sha512-jkvef+BAlqJubZdUhcyvaE84uD9XOoLR3e5GGX7YW7y8ywt0rwcGmTQHoxSMRzrJA3+Jh2T8Uy6f8TLU3WQhpQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

when I called that function like  convert('06:21pm', 'America/New_York') I am getting the result as undefined. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Well, you don't have quotes around your string, for one thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your imported script is without timezone data, try to use this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.33/moment-timezone-with-data-1970-2030.js" integrity="sha512-em60km3Olu0GWvK2C3BndCQAYhHyv637yD2PBdR1pAZnmIqjBy0nzKOu64Qx7Q9yesAlFRwvP4GK0gP9jIvM2w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```